# Unable to pass an array of structs to a function

Tags: c++, struct

I'm kinda new on C++ and I'm having trouble on an exercise which is necessary to keep a name and the height of 10 people using structs.

The structs are:

```
typedef struct 
{
    char nome[50];
    float altura;
} pserhumano;

typedef struct 
{
    float dia;
    float mes;
    float ano;
 } dnasc;
```

And the functions are:

```
 void CriaData(dnasc *D[], int i)
 {
     D[i]->mes = 1 + (rand() % 12);
     D[i]->ano = 1950 + (rand() % 49);
     D[i]->dia = 1 + (rand() % 30);
 }

 void InserirNome(pserhumano *Z[])
 {
     dnasc a[10];
     for (int contador = 0; contador < 10; contador++) {
       cout << "Insira o seu nome." << endl;
       gets (Z[contador]->nome);
       cout << "Insira a sua idade." << endl;
       cin >> Z[contador]->altura;
       CriaData(&a, contador);
      } 
 }
```

This is the output on Ubuntu:

```
athos@ubuntu:~$ g++ exercicio1.cpp -w -o a
exercicio1.cpp: In function ‘void InserirNome(pserhumano**)’:
exercicio1.cpp:35:33: error: cannot convert ‘dnasc (*)[10]’ to ‘dnasc**’ for  argument ‘1’ to ‘void CriaData(dnasc**, int)’
        CriaData(&a, contador);
```

I'm having trouble to understand how to pass these arrays to the function. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Never use `gets` again.

Comment: where's the `vector`?

Comment: "dnasc a[10]" is an array, not a vector.  Which do you want to use?

Comment: There is no vector, and you want to pass in the address of the first element of a into CriaData rather than the address of the array.

Comment: Please show us your main program that calls the functions.

Comment: I translated wrong, it was an array. Its fixed now.

Comment: FYI the protugese stackoverflow is available here: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: @ravenspoint I know, I have an account there. But I asked and I didn't get any answers so I decided to try here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `a` is an array of `dnasc`
- The function `CriaData` expects an array of pointers to `dnasc`

Change to :

```
 void CriaData(dnasc D[], int i)
 {
     D[i].mes = 1 + (rand() % 12);
     D[i].ano = 1950 + (rand() % 49);
     D[i].dia = 1 + (rand() % 30);
 }
```

And simply call:

```
CriaData(a, contador);
```

**Notes:**

- Do not use `gets`, it is unsafe. Use `std::cin`
- In your code you are using **arrays**, not **[vectors](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)**.

Comment: in portuguese we called it "vetor", which I guessed it was a vector. I guess I didn't get the translation right.

Comment: Personally I prefer "void CriaData(dnasc *D, ...) {...}" and "CriaData(a, ...);".  Can also use "CriaData(&a[0], ...);".  Also "vector" has a different meaning-- it is a class in the STL.

Answer (score 2):

I'll go differently compared to the other answers. IMHO, What you really want is:

```
void CriaData(dnasc &D) {
  D.mes = 1 + (rand() % 12);
  D.ano = 1950 + (rand() % 49);
  D.dia = 1 + (rand() % 30);
}
```

(i.e., Just to pass a `dnasc` object by reference).

and then in the loop just call:

```
dnasc a[10];
for(int contador = 0; contador < 10; ++i) {
  ...
  CriaData(a[contador]);
}
```

No need to pass in the function useless subscripts etc.

Furthermore, if your compiler supports C++11 then you could use the new [random number generation facilities](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/). In this very nice [talk](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful) Stephan T. Lavavej explains why you should not use `rand()` anymore.

Answer (score 1):

The type of `a` in `InserirNome` is **an array of 10 `dnasc`**.

The type of `&a` is a pointer to **an array of 10 `dnasc`**. In C++, that is `dnasc (*)[10]`.

This cannot be converted to `dnasc**`, which is the expected argument type of `CriaData`.

That's the compiler error message when you use

```
CriaData(&a, contador);
```

The following changes to `CriaData` should make it easier.

```
 void CriaData(dnasc D[], int i)
 {
     D[i].mes = 1 + (rand() % 12);
     D[i].ano = 1950 + (rand() % 49);
     D[i].dia = 1 + (rand() % 30);
 }
```

Then, you can call it using:

```
CriaData(a, contador);
```

Answer (score 1):

The first parameter of function `CriaData` has type `dnasc *D[]` that is adjasted to type `dnasc **D`

```
 void CriaData(dnasc *D[], int i)
```

But you call the function passing an expression of type `dnasc( * )[10]` that is you pass a pointer to local array `dnasc a[10];`

```
CriaData(&a, contador);
```

The correct function declaration would look as

```
 void CriaData(dnasc D[], int i);
```

and the corresponding its call would look as

```
CriaData(a, contador);
```

Though I do not see a sense in calling this function for this local array.